# Cypress.io doesn't persist Auth0 login for Angular app

Tags: angular, testing, cypress, auth0

I followed the Auth0 tutorial (https://auth0.com/blog/end-to-end-testing-with-cypress-and-auth0/) for using Cypress.io but I'm not able to get Cypress to persist a successful sign-in.

I am able to sign in with the Cypress Login command, but as soon as I redirect to another page, my auth.guard (which checks for Auth0 login status), prompts for login again and I get this error in Cypress:

```
myapp.auth0.com refused to connect.
```

And in the console: `Refused to frame 'https://myapp.auth0.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'none'".`

So the auth guard is not finding the login. I suspect this might be because Cypress is clearing cookies and local storage, but I haven't found a workaround.

I tried adding this (from some old code I had) to the top of the test file, but it didn't help.

```
const clear = Cypress.LocalStorage.clear
Cypress.LocalStorage.clear = function (keys, ls, rs) {
  if (keys) {  }
}
```

And in the test:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    cy.restoreLocalStorageCache();
  });

...

afterEach(() => {
    cy.saveLocalStorageCache();
  });
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: I have a workaround that I'm using for now. It's not perfect, but it's enough to keep going. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have a workaround that I'm using for now. It's not perfect, but it's enough to keep going. (Edit: I can't get the code formatting to work)

1. I set up a separate application in Auth0 for testing and I allowed username/password login for this application. (My prod app does not allow that option.)
2. Login programmatically from the first test to run (based on the Auth0 samples) and write the auth0 token to cookies.

   describe('Login', () => {
   beforeEach(() => {
   cy.restoreLocalStorageCache();
   });

   it('Should successfully login', () => {
   cy.login()
   .then((resp) => {
   return resp;
   })
   .then((body) => {
   const {access_token, expires_in, id_token} = body;
   const auth0State = {
   nonce: '',
   state: 'some-random-state'
   };

   ```
        // write access token to user-token cookie
        cy.setCookie('user-token', access_token);

        const callbackUrl = `/callback#access_token=${access_token}&scope=openid&id_token=${id_token}&expires_in=${expires_in}&token_type=Bearer&state=${auth0State.state}`;
        cy.visit(callbackUrl, {
          onBeforeLoad(win) {
            win.document.cookie = 'com.auth0.auth.some-random-state=' + JSON.stringify(auth0State);
          }
        });
      })
   ```

   });

   afterEach(() => {
   cy.saveLocalStorageCache();
   });
   });
3. For each test, preserve the token cookie:

   // cypress clears localStorage by default but we want the user data so override
   const clear = Cypress.LocalStorage.clear
   Cypress.LocalStorage.clear = function (keys, ls, rs) {
   if (keys) {  }
   };
   // cookies with these names will not be cleared before each test runs
   Cypress.Cookies.defaults({
   preserve: 'user-token'
   });

   ...

   describe('Loads Page', function() {
   beforeEach(() => {
   cy.restoreLocalStorageCache();
   // before each test automatically preserve a cookie. it will not be cleared before the NEXT test starts
   Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce('user_token');
   });

   it('Page Loads', function() {
   cy.visit(testUrl);
   cy.contains('test words');
   cy.url().should('include', testUrl);
   })

   afterEach(() => {
   cy.saveLocalStorageCache();
   });
   })

BTW - I also tried adding login to the auth guard, but I don't think it works

```
// @ts-ignore
    if (window.Cypress) {
      const auth0credentials = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("auth0Cypress")!);
      const user = auth0credentials.body.decodedToken.user;
      const access_token = auth0credentials.body.access_token;

      // debugging output
      console.log('Cypress user:', user.name);
      console.log('Cypress access_token:', access_token);
      this._cookie.put('user-token', access_token);

      if(user.name === 'test' && access_token) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return this.auth.isAuthenticated$.pipe(
          tap(loggedIn => {
            if (!loggedIn) {
              } else {
                this.auth.login(state.url);
              }
            })
          );
      };
    }
```

Comment: I could not get this work for me, when I try to route somewhere it sends me to the log in page for Auth0